# No code coverage driver is available with a remote XDebug + Nebeans

Tags: selenium, netbeans, code-coverage, netbeans-8, php-7

I installed Netbeans 8.2 (on Fedora 24) and a web server with PHP7+XDebug .
The debugger works well with Netbeans but when I execute a test generated by Netbeans, I have this message :

```
"/usr/bin/php" "/usr/local/bin/phpunit" "--colors" "--log-json" "/tmp/nb-phpunit-log.json" "--coverage-clover" "/tmp/nb-phpunit-coverage.xml" "/home/karima/netbeans-dev-201608060002/php/phpunit/NetBeansSuite.php" "--" "--run=/home/karima/git/App/tests/selenium"
    PHP Fatal error:  Class 'WebDriverCapabilityType' not found in /home/karima/git/App/tests/selenium/htdocs/indexTest.php on line 22
    PHPUnit 5.4.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

    Error:         No code coverage driver is available

    Done.
```

Here the simple test :

```
class indexTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * @var \RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected $webDriver;

    public function setUp() {
        $capabilities = array(\WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'firefox');
        $this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://app/', $capabilities);
    }

    public function tearDown() {
        $this->webDriver->close();
    }

    protected $url = 'http://www.netbeans.org/';

    public function testSimple() {
        $this->webDriver->get($this->url);
        // checking that page title contains word 'Test'
        $this->assertContains('Test', $this->webDriver->getTitle());
    }

}
```

Howto install the coverage driver in netbeans on linux (Fedora 24) for a remote server ? (and the framework of Selenium ?)

Or have you a good doc (step by step) ?

UPDATE 1 : The file /tmp/nb-phpunit-coverage.xml is empty... I created a [bug report.](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=267496)

Thanks

Comment: Selenium address functional testing where the coverage relates to the requirements or use cases. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: For the moment, I try to test Netbeans. I just click on create a test on the index page with only phpinfo. 
For info... the file /tmp/nb-phpunit-coverage.xml is empty... I search.. why ?

Answer (score 0):

I found.

There are 3 problems.

**Install the basic tools of Netbeans**

First, Netbeans didn't install  the necessary tools for its interfaces. So, you have to install manually PHPUnit and the other tools (for inspect/format, etc.).Here the best method for me :

I installed composer. After, I installed the Netbeans's tools in my environment of development. :

```
sudo dnf install composer
# necessary tools for Netbeans
composer global require friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer 
composer global require phpmd/phpmd
composer global require phpunit/phpunit
...
```

Sometimes Netbeans detect these tools. When it cannot find the good path, in the options of Netbeans, you have to precise the good path.

Composer pushes these tools in "~/.config/composer/vendor/".
After, the problem with PHPunit disappears.

**Secondly, the problems of Selenium.**

Here, my objective will  execute the first test generated by Netbeans.

You need to follow these steps:

Step 1: Install the webdriver

```
# driver for selenium/php
composer global require facebook/webdriver
```

Step 2: Change the code of test in Netbeans. You need to replace the include path.

```
set_include_path('/home/karima/.config/composer');

use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

class MyFirstTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * @var \RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected $webDriver;

    public function setUp() {
        $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
        $this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', $capabilities);
    }

    public function tearDown() {
        $this->webDriver->close();
    }

    protected $url = 'http://www.netbeans.org/';

    public function testSimple() {
        $this->webDriver->get($this->url);
        // checking that page title contains word 'NetBeans'
        $this->assertContains('NetBeans', $this->webDriver->getTitle());
    }

}
```

Step 3: Download and uncompressed the last release of [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Step 4: Move geckodriver in a system's path

```
mv geckodriver  /usr/bin/.
```

Step 5: Download the JAR of [Selenium Standalone Server](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) (I tested with 3.0.0-beta2)

Step 6: Start the selenium server :

```
java -jar /home/karima/Téléchargements/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar
```

Step 7: You can now run the test in Netbeans without error but...

**No code coverage driver is available...**

I search again...

I hope it will help others.